# Is there a performance advantage to defining numbers as parameters in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, vectorization

I am experimenting with writing vectorized FORTRAN subroutines to be incorporated in the Abaqus finite element solver. Some learning materials define constant numbers which are used in formulae as parameters in the beginning of the code, e.g.:

```
parameter ( zero = 0.d0, one = 1.d0, two = 2.d0, third = 1.d0 / 3.d0, half = 0.5d0, op5 = 1.5d0)
```

So instead of writing `0.5 * a` one would write `half * a`. Is there a performance advantage to this?

**EDIT**: I dug deeper and found this in page 11 (slide A3.22) of [this file](http://imechanica.org/files/appendix3-vumat.pdf):

> The PARAMETER assignments yield accurate floating point constant
>   definitions on any platform.

Comment: Where did you find the quote or is it your interpretation of Vladimir F's answer? In the later case I don't think he wrote /  intended that.

Comment: @albert Added the source. It's an educational slide deck by the company that makes the software.

Comment: Indeed what I thought, for this special case the quote is valid (as they use the d0 construct), but in general it is not valid for the `PARAMETER` statement, it is only guaranteed when the programmer takes care of it and uses the `PARAMETER` in his code. A problem with slides is also the there is a story told as well and the slide is just an abstract of the points to remember.

Comment: I still don't get it. I fail to see any advantage of `two` over `2.d0` regarding performance (produces the same code), clarity (math is universal, English not) or convenience (maybe you could hide the kind precision as an implementation detail, but even this is arguable, as "explicit is better than implicit"). Anyways, I'd probably use just `2` most of the time and the corecion will assure the precision to the expression type

Comment: It may have something to do with the following: (1) The code is used to implement complex material behavior, which is very hard to test. and (2) This interface tends to be very slow to change, so there may be legacy issues that's not disclosed.

Comment: Your **parameter statement** is a deprecated feature of Fortran now. You should use `parameter` as an attribute and not a statement, wherever possible. For example, `real(real64), parameter :: zero = 0._real64, ...`, where `real64` comes from the `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module of Fortran.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no performance difference whatsoever. The generated code will be exactly the same. It is probably used just to make using these numbers more convenient or (supposedly) readable.

BUT you must be careful. Just 0.5 is a (default) single precision number. You must use the way used in the constant definition. `0.5d0` is double precision and the constant will help you not to forget the `d0`. In binary number formats 0.5 is exactly re presentable anyway but one third, for example, is not.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that accuracy was the goal. Edited the question to reflect that.